# Check For Installed Application

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my application, i want to do some task if there is PARTICULAR APPLICATION installed in windows phone. 
Is there any way using which we can verify that either application in installed or not ?

for example, can i determine through some code that either facebook messenger is installed or not ?

Currently i don't have any clue about how to accomplish that. 
If anyone knows then please share it. 
thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I know there is a private API, which is documented on MSDN as well.

Comment: yeah i found one here, 
[link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager.findpackages.aspx
but i don't know how to use it. 
can you please give example code ?

Comment: As you said on the other comment, "this api is not intended to be used directly from your code". This means you don't have the right to use it.

Comment: isn't there any other way to do it ??

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the list of all installed applications on the phone currently. You may access only those that are by the same publisher ID using:

[`InstallationManager.FindPackagesFromCurrentPublisher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager.findpackagesforcurrentpublisher).

> Returns all the app packages with the same publisher ID as the app calling this method.

Comment: i think i found what i am looking for but still don't know how to use it, here it is,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager.findpackages.aspx

Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackages("", "");

in msdn they have said that it takes two arguments, but it is not working for me, it gives an error that "No overload for method 'FindPackages' takes 2 arguments" and "this api is not intended to be used directly from your code".
i can't proceed further. 
please help.

Comment: As I said, there is no API that you can use. That API is reserved for. Microsoft and specific approved applications from OEMs.